# Add text field with text paragraph in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, textfield, richtext

I am trying to add a text field inside the paragraph in flutter but not getting success below screen shot what I want to achive.

[image]

I am trying the below code

```
 RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        text: "“",
        style: TextStyle(
            color:
                const Color(0xff56A1D5),
            fontSize: 20.sp),
        children: <InlineSpan>[
        WidgetSpan(
            child: Text(
            "I want to talk with you about ",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: const Color(
                    0xff506274),
                fontSize: 20.sp),
            ),
        ),
        const WidgetSpan(
            child: SizedBox(
            width: 120,
            child: TextField(
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.all(0),
                ),
            ),
            ),
        ),
        WidgetSpan(
            child: Text(
            "(the actions, attitude, or behavior)",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: const Color(
                    0xff506274),
                fontSize: 20.sp),
            ),
        ),
        ],
    ),
  ),
```

But My output is look like below.

[image]

Can anyone show me where I am going to wrong or How can I achieve the same as the above image without leaving extra space?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly right. as `(the actions, attitude, or behavior)` this text does not fit in the screen it came into a new line. For checking this reduce your text then you may understand the issue.

Your code output when I run your code:

**Desktop:**

[image]

**Mobile:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, nagendra for the reply but I want word wrap for the text data after text field

Comment: did you find any ways to wrap word in text?

Comment: Yes multiline property but it will not work.